# Django template use custom filter in CSS

Tags: css, django

```
@register.filter(name='cf')
def cf(amount):
    # Format the amount as an integer with commas
    formatted_amount = f"{int(amount):,}"

    # Determine the CSS class based on the sign of the amount
    if amount < 0:
        css_class = "red-text"
    else:
        css_class = "green-text"

    print(formatted_amount)
    # Generate the HTML markup with the CSS class and formatted amount
    return f'<span class="{css_class}">{formatted_amount}</span>'
```

I am using the custom_filter inside the HTML, and the output is

```
<span class="green-text">5,492</span>
```

I just need '5,492' in green color, but it prints as above

Please guide me to rectify it.

Comment: What are you expecting to return from the function, it looks to be working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call [mark_safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe) to mark string so django renders it in template.

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

@register.filter(name='cf')
def cf(amount):
   # Format the amount as an integer with commas
    formatted_amount = f"{int(amount):,}"

    # Determine the CSS class based on the sign of the amount
    if amount < 0:
       css_class = "red-text"
    else:
        css_class = "green-text"

    print(formatted_amount)
    # Generate the HTML markup with the CSS class and formatted amount
    return mark_safe(f'<span class="{css_class}">{formatted_amount}</span>')
```

Comment: Thanks, my mistake was not defining red-text, green-text, after defining that and using 'safe' it's working as expected